# Failed to compile using gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to compile while this error happened.

```
c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/build.make:76: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/src/otpch.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/src/otpch.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/src/otpch.cpp.o'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is error 4 and what could be causnig it?

Comment: This means that either your RAM is defective of you should submit a bug.  If other programs that work for others crash on your computer, it is likely your RAM being defective. If you can reproduce the crash consistently and compilation always crashes the same way, it is likely a GCC bug. In this latter case, you can use [C-Reduce](https://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/) to shorten it to the smallest input that triggers the crash before submitting it as a bug report (assuming it is still present in the development version and not already reported).

Comment: I have *never* ICEd from bad RAM. Compilers are *really* buggy.

Comment: If you wanted less general advice, you should have posted repro code.

Comment: [otpch.cpp](https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver/blob/master/src/otpch.cpp) There you go, and in wiki there is how to compile ( i am using ubuntu 16.04) @CodyGray

Comment: Hmm, no. A GitHub link to an entire project is not what I meant. You need to post a [MCVE]. No one should have to download an entire project and learn how to build it just to repro a compiler error.

Comment: @CodyGray I succeed on compiling it in all of my PCs ( windows/ubuntu/mac) while i am still getting this error in OVH dedicated hosts.